# Conditional formatting excel conundrum

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a list of values in excel.

I would like to highlight a cell if its more than 1.5 higher or lower than the value before it or after it.

Is this possible?

Thanks guys!!

Comment: If nothing else, Conditional Formatting can use formulas. You just need to write one that will return a Boolean TRUE or FALSE based on the criteria you want to use for formatting. If you can provide a sheet or screenshot of some example data and headers, it would make it easier for us to help you write one.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you put in for conditional formatting depends on the address of the active cell at the time you set the conditional format. So if the active cell is E5, and the cells before it and after it are E4 and E6, the formula would be something like:

`=OR(E5/E4>1.5,E4/E5>1.5,E5/E6>1.5,E6/E5>1.5)`

Excel will automatically adjust the formula as necessary for the other cells in the range.

What version of Excel are you using?